# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named my package but I can find it in pip freeze

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, python-3.6

I tried to make a custom package [(link)][1]
like this

```
[ '|-- willytricks',
  '    |-- __init__.py',
  '    |-- directoryList.md',
  '    |-- setup.py',
  '    |-- trick.py',
  '    |-- build',
  '    |   |-- bdist.linux-x86_64',
  '    |-- dist',
  '    |   |-- willytricks-0.0.1-py3.6.egg',
  '    |   |-- willytricks-0.0.1.tar.gz',
  '    |-- willytricks.egg-info',
  '        |-- PKG-INFO',
  '        |-- SOURCES.txt',
  '        |-- dependency_links.txt',
  '        |-- top_level.txt',
  '
]
```

the setup.py :

```
import setuptools

setuptools.setup(
    name="willytricks",
    version="0.0.1",
    author="wil75822",
    author_email="lunasdejavu@gmail.com",
    description="",
    long_description=" useful python tools",
    long_description_content_type="text",
    url="www.ntu.edu.tw",
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    classifiers=[
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
        "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
        "Operating System :: OS Independent",
    ],
)
```

then I type `python setup.py sdist`

```
sudo pip3 install "~/dist/willytricks-0.0.1.tar.gz"
```

I can find it by `pip3 freeze`
the information:

```
willytricks @ file:///data/workspace/willy_sung/willytricks/dist/willytricks-0.0.1.tar.gz
```

but I can't `import willytricks` in python3

```
import willytricks
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'willytricks'
```

thank you guys! after following your tips I can import willytricks now
but it shows another error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/data/workspace/willy_sung/myproject/dist/willytricks-0.0.1/willytricks/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from trick import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'trick'
```

what should I put inside of **init**.py?
[1]: https://l.messenger.com/l.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fdrive.google.com%2Ffile%2Fd%2F1rrS_JzOMcwx7b_-6xkF85Jo8GQnp3H0M%2Fview%3Fusp%3Dsharing&h=AT1V7YbJgVgstXoSU7qiD6wdO-rjPdcXjNJ6HVTWfZ0y-zNFF4nSiLBvXZRDU8OC05PiZZGg8V9VyecHgxUJdlrKR152cyh5VUALDtdFE4KZ3RQsfe8yR9rznQLflTbwr2o

Comment: Your distribution does not contain any package (folder with `__init__.py`). Most libraries contain a package named after the library that will be imported.

Comment: setup.py should be one directory above willytricks.

Answer (score 1):

Python distribution packages don't have to be named the same as the scripts, modules and packages they actually deliver. When you ran `setup.py` in `willytricks` it didn't find any packages, and it built a "willytricks" distribution without any packages in it.

If I run the scanner manually,

```
>>> import os
>>> os.getcwd()
'/home/td/tmp/bbb/willytricks'
>>> import setuptools
>>> setuptools.find_packages()
[]
```

But if I go back a directory and scan again, a package is found

```
>>> os.chdir("..")
>>> os.getcwd()
'/home/td/tmp/packagedir'
>>> setuptools.find_packages()
['willytricks']
```

You need to move `setup.py`, and everything that is not part of the package up one directory. This directory can be named anything. In fact its common to name it the same as the package. Its common to use source control and you could have multiple copies of these files checked out in different directories at the same time.

Change your structure to the following and it should work.

```
<projectdir>--|-- willytricks
  |           |-- __init__.py
  |           |-- trick.py
  |-- directoryList.md
  |-- setup.py
  |-- build
        ...
  |-- dist
        ...
  |-- willytricks.egg-info
        ...
```

**Scripts and Modules and Packages**

A python "package" is a directory with .py modules and subpackages. Its a bit unfortunate that we end up talking about packaging packages. Modules and packages are installed into background directories known by python (perhaps `site-packages` or `dist-packages` somewhere in the python distribution). Top level scripts are also .py files but are usually located where the operating system can find them in the system `PATH`.

Since you have a package with only one module, you could easily distribute it as a single module instead. You only need a package if you have multiple python modules that you want to group together - or plan to do so in the future. For a single module distribution, you can go back to your original structure and remove `__init__.py`. In `setup.py` remove `packages=setuptools.find_packages(),` and add `py_modules=["Tricks"],`. Now, `import tricks` would work. You could also rename that .py to `willytricks.py` for `import willytricks` to work.

Comment: thanks a lot for your explanation in detail.I can import  willytricks now but there is something wrong in my __init__.py. there is only one line  "from trick import *" in it and all the codes in trick are simple functions. what should I write in __init__.py?

Comment: Since you only have 1 module, `trick.py`, you don't need to make a package out of it. In your original directory structure you could have used `py_modules = ["trick"]` to distribute just the module. I'll add some text to the answer.

Comment: If you plan to add more .py files to your package of tricks in the future, just keep what you are doing now.